# Maintaining text colour change in a breakable tcolorbox

Tags: color, boxes, tcolorbox

I try to maintain the current text colour in breakable boxes from `tcolorbox`, but the manual clearly states (see manual of the current version, section 15.2, page 292, version 3.34)

> • If your text content contains some text color changing commands,
>   your color will not survive the break to the next box.

So, this has to fail (right now). However, colour changes are maintained in explicit
TeX boxes, being split using `\vsplit`.

Is there a way (i.e. hack/patch) to force `tcolorbox` to maintain the current text colour from one part of the broken box to the next one?

A grouping with `{ \color{....}...}` or `\begingroup \color{...}...\endgroup` or `\textcolor{...}{...}` does not work neither.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
  \blindtext[3]
  \color{blue}  % To 'force' color change 
  \blindtext[3]
  \color{red}
  \blindtext
  \color{brown}
  \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

The colour should be blue on the upper half of the second box if it would work ;-)

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have a good answer to this question, but, obviously, I do not have one. `\vsplit` is used internally, but coloring is not really supported for this command, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150780/color-bleeding-when-using-vsplit-for-a-box-with-colored-text and David Carlisles answer to this. Changing color setting for the current `tcolorbox` implementation is very touchy since I put in a great deal of time to get it like it is now. It is not perfect and has same drawbacks, but it circumvents a lot of problems.

Comment: Nevertheless, if there are new insights in how to enhance the current implementation (for all use cases, for pdflatex, for xelatex, ... ) I'm willing to give it a new try :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks for your comment(s) ... Isn't it possible to store the color and restore it in the next (continued) box?

Comment: xelatex also has a special color bug which I cannot test on my system, but is circumvented currently, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186139/last-xelatex-colors-text-in-white-in-some-circumstances/201611#201611

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: I've read your question from your link above and this is, what I feared ;-) Interestingly I need color bleeding where you want to prevent it ... The double grouping is new to me. I will ask David if he has some clue anyway.

Comment: I don't have much hope in the moment, but you never know ;-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Otherwise, `\vsplit` boxes keep the colour, as I have realized (still new to 'TeX' programming), I would really like to use your `breakable` boxes, although I my particular case I don't need the other features of your marvellous package

Comment: Basically it's not possible to get this right in TeX (@ThomasF.Sturm)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Unrelated: A question for you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220153/marginalia-inside-tcolorbox

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. I tried to answer this other question now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With xelatex or lualatex you could color the font instead of using the color commands. This would survive a box break:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
  \blindtext[3]
  \addfontfeatures{Color=blue}
  \blindtext[3]
  \addfontfeatures{Color=red}
  \blindtext
  \addfontfeatures{Color=brown}
  \blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a new idea... I am currently not using xelatex nor lualatex... I'll give it a try!

Comment: Be aware that the font color always wins. You can't use something like \textcolor{yellow}{yellow} with it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you think it would make sense to have an option to color package so it used the font attribute as well as (or instead of?) the color special, so that `\textcolor{yellow}{...}` would combine with this?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It would certainly worth consideration. But as I wrote such font colors wins but they don't affect all fonts - only the one loaded with `\setmainfont` etc (and so no rules and without unicode-math no math). And the combination with color commands can lead to curious effects. E.g. after adding colors to the fonts  the math will be red with `\textcolor{red}{$a=b$}`, but `\textcolor{red}{blbla $a=b$}` it will be black (with luatex, with xetex is is red again). So imho some careful investigations are needed.