# Using \marginnote in \tcolorbox in tufte-latex

Tags: tcolorbox, tufte

The `tufte-book` class provides a `\marginnote` command for putting notes in the margin. I am using the `tcolorbox` package to create a sort of environment that has a border, and I would like to be able to use `\marginnote` inside a `tcolorbox`, but I get the complaint `Float(s) lost`. I'm guessing both `tcolorbox` and `\marginnote` use floats in their implementation, and I understand that nested floats are disallowed, but I don't see any real reason that one shouldn't be able to align margin notes with text in a non-floating `tcolorbox`. Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{exbox}{}                                                          

\begin{document}

\begin{exbox}
Test\marginnote{Note}
\end{exbox}

\end{document}
```

Adding in `nofloat` as an option to the `tcolorbox` doesn't seem to make any difference; it is supposed to be initially set anyhow.

Is there some way to allow one to have equivalent functionality to the `\marginnote` command that behaves the same inside and outside a `tcolorbox`?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220153/marginalia-inside-tcolorbox.

Comment: @TeXnician This one doesn't compile, your link points to an example in which the code doesn't do what the OP wants it to do.

Comment: @JPi I'm not sure whether that's correct. Of course the linked example uses a hacky way, but effectively solves the problem (you do not have to expand any background into margin).

Comment: `tufte-book` does all sorts of low level stuff that doesn't always get along with other packages.  The problem is the same if you use `\marginpar` but disappears when you replace the `tufte-book` class with `book` or `memoir.`

Comment: @TeXnician: ok..

Comment: @JPi Okay, you're right, it's a `tufte-book` problem. The example in the link works just fine, but not for `tufte`.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure boxes like those created by tcolorbox mesh with Tufte's philosophy, e.g. the content to ink ratio.

Comment: The `tcolorbox` I'm actually using has very little extra ink -- just a border line on one side. I just left the default style for the MWE. Perhaps there is another way to get an environment with such a line, breakable across pages, but `tcolorbox` seemed pretty straightforward.

Comment: The problem is, that you cannot use floating material inside a box. `\marginnote` from the package `marginnote` can be used, because it is implemented to be non-floating. `tufte-book` defines its own `\marginnote` which seems to be floating...

Comment: Is there a way to load the `marginnote` package in a `tufte-book` document? If I try to do it I get the error `Command \marginnote already defined`.

Answer (score 4):

You can map the \marginnote command to `\marginpar`, this can then be used by the `\marginnote` from tufte:

```
\RequirePackage{marginnote}
\let\marginpar\marginnote
\let\marginnote\undefined

\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{exbox}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{exbox}
Test\marginnote{Note}
\end{exbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]