# Are there any shaded theorems usable with tufte sidenote/marginnote?

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed, tufte, ntheorem

I would like to use tuftes sidenote and marginnote commands. Is there any way to use them in combination with shaded theorems? I tried `tcolorbox` and `mdframed`, but both seem to be problematic. 
The redefinition as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354193/using-marginnote-in-tcolorbox-in-tufte-latex) leads sometimes to strange effects. Therefore I am looking for an alternative theorem packages which can be shaded.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{TcbTheorem}{Theorem}{
    colback=blue!5, colframe=blue!5, coltitle=red,
}{thm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{TcbTheorem}{Name}{ref}
            \lipsum[1]
                \sidenote{sidenote}
            \marginnote{marginnote}
    \end{TcbTheorem}
\end{document}
```