# Set text background color *without* mdframed or tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, mdframed, backgrounds, tufte

It's a known issue of `tufte-*` that `\sidenote` and `\marginnote` won't build if used inside `mdframed` environments or `tcolorbox`es. I'm not finding a workaround for that, and most posts on the topic suggest there isn't one.

What I want is simply to put a nice gray background behind some paragraphs in a `tufte-handout`. Can this be done *without* `mdframed` or `tcolorbox`?

EDIT: Minimal example

```latex
\documentclass[nobib,justified]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
  linecolor=lightgray,
  linewidth=3pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt
]{graybox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{graybox}
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{This is a marginnote}
\end{graybox}

\end{document}
```

Fails to build with `! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.`

Comment: Could you add a runable, minimal example code whichs shows the problem?

Comment: It can be done with the `shaded` environment (from Donald Arseneau's ` framed` package), which can break across pages.

Comment: @Bernard: are you sure? I just tested and the side note doesn't show up.

Comment: Side notes are in the margin? `Shaded`, unless you patch it , shades only the text area width. Could you post a small code reproducing your problem?

Comment: See here for "tufte":    https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366097/46023

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of a stupid hack that may have *a lot* of bugs, but it seems to work for short paragraphs away from page breaks.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{grayground}{%
    \noindent\smash{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!20, colframe=gray!20, oversize, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, left=4pt, right=4pt, box align=top]
    \let\sidenote\@gobble
    \let\marginnote\@gobble
    \color{gray!20}\BODY
    \end{tcolorbox}}\par\BODY}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{grayground}
\blindtext\sidenote{\blindtext}\blindtext
\end{grayground}

\end{document}
```

### Explanation

The basic idea is to first print the text once using `tcolorbox`, but suppress any `sidenote` or `marginnote`, with the text the same color as the background to hide it.

Then we print the *real* text, with active sidenote and margin note on top of it.

Now, I am counting on the measurement of the version with the sidenote superscripts and the version without to be very similar, so while the two texts are not exactly the same they should take up roughly the same amount of vertical space and so you can get away with this.

To implement this, you can just use a `tcolorbox` to do the first round of printing. Then you smash it.

Inside the `tcolorbox` you can let `marginnote` and `sidenote` to `@gobble` to suppress their function. You finish by printing the same text again.

To make it easier to use you can wrap everything inside an Environ.

The output looks something like this (image is slightly out-of-date; I made some adjustments in the code to make the fit a bit better).

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's some hackery!

Comment: Not robust enough for production unfortunately. The page break behavior is quite erratic.

Comment: yeah.. that's just an idea. Page breaks will be hard to handle in general.