# Breackable tcolorbox: wrong odd/even page recognition

Tags: tcolorbox

`Tcolorbox` package does not corect recognize odd/even. A primer from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220153/marginalia-inside-tcolorbox) does not work correct any more for twosided documents

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage[breakable, many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\printpage{%
Page is \thepage. It is \checkoddpage\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi.
}

\NewTColorBox{SomeBox}{+O{}}{%
  breakable, enhanced,
  check odd page,
  lowerbox=ignored,
underlay={%
  if odd page={%
     \draw[red!75!black,line width=1pt]
     (frame.north east)
     --(frame.south west);%
   }{%
     \draw[red!75!black,line width=1pt]
     (frame.north west)
     --(frame.south east);%
   },
},%
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{SomeBox}

\printpage

\lipsum*

\bigskip
\printpage
\end{SomeBox}
\printpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you use the `if odd page` check directly inside the box code (not inside `underlay={...}`), like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[breakable, many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\printpage{%
  Page is \thepage. It is \checkoddpage\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi.\par
}

\NewTColorBox{SomeBox}{+O{}}{%
  breakable, enhanced,
  check odd page,
  lowerbox=ignored,
  if odd page={
    underlay={
       \draw[blue!75!black,line width=1pt]
       (frame.north east)
       --(frame.south west);
    }
  }{
    underlay={
       \draw[red!75!black,line width=1pt]
       (frame.north west)
       --(frame.south east);
    }
  },
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{SomeBox}
\printpage
\lipsum*[1-3]
\par
\printpage
\end{SomeBox}

\newpage
\begin{SomeBox}
\printpage
\lipsum*[4-6]
\par
\printpage
\end{SomeBox}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

I suppose the reason why `/tcb/if odd page` doesn't work inside the argument of `/tcb/underlay` is that `/tcb/if odd page` is a `tcolorbox` key, not 〈graphical code〉 (TikZ code, etc.) as expected for the value passed to the `/tcb/underlay` style.

When a box using the `/tcb/breakable` key is broken across pages, all parts get the same result for the check, which appears to be done when the box starts. But by using the `tcbbreakpart` counter, you can make colors or whatever you want alternate inside a breakable box depending on the part number (which starts from 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[breakable, many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\printpage{%
  Page is \thepage. It is \checkoddpage\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi.\par
}

\NewTColorBox{SomeBox}{+O{}}{%
  breakable, enhanced,
  check odd page,
  lowerbox=ignored,
  if odd page={
    underlay={
       \ifodd\value{tcbbreakpart}
         \draw[blue!75!black,line width=1pt]
         (frame.north east) -- (frame.south west);
       \else
         \draw[red!75!black,line width=1pt]
         (frame.north west) -- (frame.south east);
       \fi
    }
  }{
    underlay={
       \ifodd\value{tcbbreakpart}
         \draw[red!75!black,line width=1pt]
         (frame.north west) -- (frame.south east);
       \else
         \draw[blue!75!black,line width=1pt]
         (frame.north east) -- (frame.south west);
       \fi
    }
  },
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{SomeBox}
\printpage
\lipsum
\par
\printpage
\end{SomeBox}

\begin{SomeBox}
\printpage
\lipsum
\par
\printpage
\end{SomeBox}

\end{document}
```

[image: 4 in 1]

Comment: But, unfortunately, if your tcolorbox is break, then the problem remains. My MWE is about breackable tcolorbox

Comment: This unwanted behawiour was broken in newest versions of tcolorbox, because some previous versions was worked. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220153/marginalia-inside-tcolorbox

Comment: AFAICS, this is different: [Thomas F. Sturm's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220330/73317) in your link uses the `\ifoddpage` macro inside `\underlay={...}`, this is not the same as the `/tcb/if odd page` PGF key (no backslash here, only forward slashes)!

Comment: Yes, that’s different then Thomas F. Sturm's answer. My MWE was an attempt to fix the problem. Thomas F. Sturm's answer doesn't work correctly anymore.

Comment: Indeed, probably things have changed in how `/tcb/underlay` is implemented. But did you see my edit?