# Problems with textcolor in tcolorboxes with page breaks

Tags: color, tcolorbox

When I use colored text (textcolor) in a - breakable - tcolorbox the color is restored to black after a page break. What must be changed to have, say, blue text within the whole tcolorbox?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % Frames
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{cleveref} % references in tcolorboxes
\usepackage{lipsum} % references in tcolorboxes

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = chapter,
crefname={beispiel}{example},
Crefname={Beispiel}{Example} ]
{Exa}{Beispiel}{%
    breakable,
    fonttitle = \bfseries,
    colframe = green!35!black,
    colback = green!5
}{exa}


\begin{document}


\begin{Exa}{Differenzialgleichung}{DGL}
\textcolor{blue}
{
\lipsum[1-10]
}
\end{Exa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `coltext = blue` in `\newtcbtheorem`?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220145/2388

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the font colour mechanism of `tcolorbox` and set it as optional argument of your `exa` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % Frames
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{cleveref} % references in tcolorboxes
\usepackage{lipsum} % references in tcolorboxes

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within = chapter,
crefname={beispiel}{example},
Crefname={Beispiel}{Example} ]
{Exa}{Beispiel}{%
    breakable,
    fonttitle = \bfseries,
    colframe = green!35!black,
    colback = green!5
}{exa}


\begin{document}


\begin{Exa}[coltext=red]{Differenzialgleichung}{DGL}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{Exa}

test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this only works if the whole text is in the same color, not if you were only coloring part of the text

Comment: @raquelhortab If you want to colour part of the text: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220145/36296