# \textcolor is reset after page break in shaded environment from framed package

Tags: page-breaking, framed

Text color is being reset after any page break in the middle of a shaded enviroment.
After searching through some other questions, I did not find my answer since:

- I'd rather not have to change to another package since I got quite a lot of personalized shaded blocks.
- The text in the shaded environment is not all the same color, there are chunks of different colors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray}

\begin{document}

\begin{shaded}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut nibh enim. Duis rutrum nisi augue, vel lacinia magna tincidunt in. Proin consectetur, urna euismod mattis tempus, turpis odio eleifend lacus, at feugiat nisl diam in lorem. Maecenas porttitor velit quis volutpat commodo. Morbi eget mi vel ante accumsan aliquet et cursus leo. Curabitur rhoncus, ex eget iaculis suscipit, lorem turpis interdum neque, non feugiat quam velit vitae augue. In accumsan ipsum vel est euismod tristique. Sed vel lacus sit amet nibh accumsan aliquam.

Nunc eget dignissim dui, vel malesuada eros. In maximus risus in auctor tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus molestie accumsan elit, nec auctor libero ultrices sed. Fusce imperdiet ultricies cursus. Praesent molestie nulla eu dui tincidunt, ut maximus leo rutrum. Aenean finibus metus eget accumsan eleifend. Nullam tincidunt erat nec arcu consectetur, vel interdum dolor volutpat. Integer accumsan suscipit tortor at sodales. Sed a accumsan justo. Integer ut faucibus elit. Vestibulum dui urna, placerat ut fringilla sed, vulputate ut mi. Integer arcu odio, placerat eu augue congue, malesuada congue tortor.

Aenean facilisis sit amet quam ac posuere. Curabitur ultrices luctus ligula eget gravida. In semper fermentum dolor, eu vehicula velit. Aliquam tincidunt nulla augue, ut feugiat nisl fringilla nec. Proin sed justo convallis, viverra sem non, dapibus lacus. Ut fermentum turpis at erat imperdiet, at hendrerit massa ultrices. Morbi interdum nulla quis consectetur lacinia. Aenean in euismod erat, nec sagittis dolor. Morbi in justo faucibus, tincidunt enim sed, volutpat ex.

Cras pulvinar magna et magna ornare fermentum. Proin rhoncus magna eu nisl euismod pellentesque. Mauris mattis turpis vitae elementum pretium. Nullam volutpat eu magna eget mollis. Phasellus at semper dolor. Suspendisse semper vitae nisl sit amet placerat. Nam id sollicitudin orci. Vestibulum vitae tortor lectus. Vivamus convallis eros turpis, quis pellentesque lorem molestie eu.

Curabitur eget finibus orci. Sed vel condimentum nunc, sodales congue lorem. Maecenas sit amet suscipit nunc, id pretium lectus. Vestibulum vel ipsum vitae magna dictum feugiat. Maecenas sodales aliquam felis, sed lobortis diam ullamcorper efficitur. Nam in sapien mauris. Cras nisl risus, finibus quis turpis in, suscipit blandit elit. Mauris rutrum porta bibendum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut nibh enim. Duis rutrum nisi augue, vel lacinia magna tincidunt in. Proin consectetur, urna euismod mattis tempus, turpis odio eleifend lacus, at feugiat nisl diam in lorem. Maecenas porttitor velit quis volutpat commodo. Morbi eget mi vel ante accumsan aliquet et cursus leo. Curabitur rhoncus, ex eget iaculis suscipit, lorem turpis interdum neque, non feugiat quam velit vitae augue. In accumsan ipsum vel est euismod tristique. Sed vel lacus sit amet nibh accumsan aliquam.

\textcolor{green}{
    Nunc eget dignissim dui, vel malesuada eros. In maximus risus in auctor tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus molestie accumsan elit, nec auctor libero ultrices sed. Fusce imperdiet ultricies cursus. Praesent molestie nulla eu dui tincidunt, ut maximus leo rutrum. Aenean finibus metus eget accumsan eleifend. Nullam tincidunt erat nec arcu consectetur, vel interdum dolor volutpat. Integer accumsan suscipit tortor at sodales. Sed a accumsan justo. Integer ut faucibus elit. Vestibulum dui urna, placerat ut fringilla sed, vulputate ut mi. Integer arcu odio, placerat eu augue congue, malesuada congue tortor.
}
Aenean facilisis sit amet quam ac posuere. Curabitur ultrices luctus ligula eget gravida. In semper fermentum dolor, eu vehicula velit. Aliquam tincidunt nulla augue, ut feugiat nisl fringilla nec. Proin sed justo convallis, viverra sem non, dapibus lacus. Ut fermentum turpis at erat imperdiet, at hendrerit massa ultrices. Morbi interdum nulla quis consectetur lacinia. Aenean in euismod erat, nec sagittis dolor. Morbi in justo faucibus, tincidunt enim sed, volutpat ex.

Cras pulvinar magna et magna ornare fermentum. Proin rhoncus magna eu nisl euismod pellentesque. Mauris mattis turpis vitae elementum pretium. Nullam volutpat eu magna eget mollis. Phasellus at semper dolor. Suspendisse semper vitae nisl sit amet placerat. Nam id sollicitudin orci. Vestibulum vitae tortor lectus. Vivamus convallis eros turpis, quis pellentesque lorem molestie eu.

Curabitur eget finibus orci. Sed vel condimentum nunc, sodales congue lorem. Maecenas sit amet suscipit nunc, id pretium lectus. Vestibulum vel ipsum vitae magna dictum feugiat. Maecenas sodales aliquam felis, sed lobortis diam ullamcorper efficitur. Nam in sapien mauris. Cras nisl risus, finibus quis turpis in, suscipit blandit elit. Mauris rutrum porta bibendum.
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Note that some text that should be shown normally (black), is not even visible...

Comment: Please, do not post code fragments. To help you, we must be able to reproduce the problem; help us with a complete code that we can compile. Thanks!

Comment: tcolorbox supports the color stack (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623232/2388). With lualatex you could use luacolor or color the font (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220145/2388).

Comment: @Rmano done, I've added a full document

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please read the first point of my question, I'm not looking for alternatives to the framed package but solutions

Comment: framed doesn't support color stacks. So either use another package or rewrite framed.

Comment: I see, so no solution? I'm trying the same code with tcolorbox and it behaves even worse, it skips a whole page before starting and does not break pages (even adding the breakable option). Could you add an answer with the correct code?

Comment: I linked to some examples with tcolorbox above.

Comment: nevermind, I've fixed it and posted it. I could have marked it as the correct answer if you posted it so you'd get the point though. I'm still not gonna mark it as solved since it is not really a solution to the question, just an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you don't want to change packages but you could stay very close in syntax by using `mdframed` rather than `framed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.5}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=shadecolor,
leftmargin=-5pt,% if you want the text to have its regular width
rightmargin=-5pt,% make the margins the negative value of inner margins
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
hidealllines
]{shaded}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{shaded}

\lipsum[1-4]

\textcolor{green}{
    \lipsum[9]
}

\lipsum[10-11]

\end{shaded}


\end{document}
```

[image: bottom of page]

[image: top of next]

Comment: that is quite more convenient since I don't need to change much, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ulrike Fischer comments, I achieved it by using tcolorbox. Still not a solution with framed though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{241, 241, 255}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}%
[use color stack,breakable,colback=shadecolor,sharp corners=all,colframe=white!]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut nibh enim. Duis rutrum nisi augue, vel lacinia magna tincidunt in. Proin consectetur, urna euismod mattis tempus, turpis odio eleifend lacus, at feugiat nisl diam in lorem. Maecenas porttitor velit quis volutpat commodo. Morbi eget mi vel ante accumsan aliquet et cursus leo. Curabitur rhoncus, ex eget iaculis suscipit, lorem turpis interdum neque, non feugiat quam velit vitae augue. In accumsan ipsum vel est euismod tristique. Sed vel lacus sit amet nibh accumsan aliquam.

Nunc eget dignissim dui, vel malesuada eros. In maximus risus in auctor tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus molestie accumsan elit, nec auctor libero ultrices sed. Fusce imperdiet ultricies cursus. Praesent molestie nulla eu dui tincidunt, ut maximus leo rutrum. Aenean finibus metus eget accumsan eleifend. Nullam tincidunt erat nec arcu consectetur, vel interdum dolor volutpat. Integer accumsan suscipit tortor at sodales. Sed a accumsan justo. Integer ut faucibus elit. Vestibulum dui urna, placerat ut fringilla sed, vulputate ut mi. Integer arcu odio, placerat eu augue congue, malesuada congue tortor.

Aenean facilisis sit amet quam ac posuere. Curabitur ultrices luctus ligula eget gravida. In semper fermentum dolor, eu vehicula velit. Aliquam tincidunt nulla augue, ut feugiat nisl fringilla nec. Proin sed justo convallis, viverra sem non, dapibus lacus. Ut fermentum turpis at erat imperdiet, at hendrerit massa ultrices. Morbi interdum nulla quis consectetur lacinia. Aenean in euismod erat, nec sagittis dolor. Morbi in justo faucibus, tincidunt enim sed, volutpat ex.

Cras pulvinar magna et magna ornare fermentum. Proin rhoncus magna eu nisl euismod pellentesque. Mauris mattis turpis vitae elementum pretium. Nullam volutpat eu magna eget mollis. Phasellus at semper dolor. Suspendisse semper vitae nisl sit amet placerat. Nam id sollicitudin orci. Vestibulum vitae tortor lectus. Vivamus convallis eros turpis, quis pellentesque lorem molestie eu.

Curabitur eget finibus orci. Sed vel condimentum nunc, sodales congue lorem. Maecenas sit amet suscipit nunc, id pretium lectus. Vestibulum vel ipsum vitae magna dictum feugiat. Maecenas sodales aliquam felis, sed lobortis diam ullamcorper efficitur. Nam in sapien mauris. Cras nisl risus, finibus quis turpis in, suscipit blandit elit. Mauris rutrum porta bibendum.

\textcolor{green}{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut nibh enim. Duis rutrum nisi augue, vel lacinia magna tincidunt in. Proin consectetur, urna euismod mattis tempus, turpis odio eleifend lacus, at feugiat nisl diam in lorem. Maecenas porttitor velit quis volutpat commodo. Morbi eget mi vel ante accumsan aliquet et cursus leo. Curabitur rhoncus, ex eget iaculis suscipit, lorem turpis interdum neque, non feugiat quam velit vitae augue. In accumsan ipsum vel est euismod tristique. Sed vel lacus sit amet nibh accumsan aliquam.
    Nunc eget dignissim dui, vel malesuada eros. In maximus risus in auctor tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus molestie accumsan elit, nec auctor libero ultrices sed. Fusce imperdiet ultricies cursus. Praesent molestie nulla eu dui tincidunt, ut maximus leo rutrum. Aenean finibus metus eget accumsan eleifend. Nullam tincidunt erat nec arcu consectetur, vel interdum dolor volutpat. Integer accumsan suscipit tortor at sodales. Sed a accumsan justo. Integer ut faucibus elit. Vestibulum dui urna, placerat ut fringilla sed, vulputate ut mi. Integer arcu odio, placerat eu augue congue, malesuada congue tortor.
}
Aenean facilisis sit amet quam ac posuere. Curabitur ultrices luctus ligula eget gravida. In semper fermentum dolor, eu vehicula velit. Aliquam tincidunt nulla augue, ut feugiat nisl fringilla nec. Proin sed justo convallis, viverra sem non, dapibus lacus. Ut fermentum turpis at erat imperdiet, at hendrerit massa ultrices. Morbi interdum nulla quis consectetur lacinia. Aenean in euismod erat, nec sagittis dolor. Morbi in justo faucibus, tincidunt enim sed, volutpat ex.

Cras pulvinar magna et magna ornare fermentum. Proin rhoncus magna eu nisl euismod pellentesque. Mauris mattis turpis vitae elementum pretium. Nullam volutpat eu magna eget mollis. Phasellus at semper dolor. Suspendisse semper vitae nisl sit amet placerat. Nam id sollicitudin orci. Vestibulum vitae tortor lectus. Vivamus convallis eros turpis, quis pellentesque lorem molestie eu.

Curabitur eget finibus orci. Sed vel condimentum nunc, sodales congue lorem. Maecenas sit amet suscipit nunc, id pretium lectus. Vestibulum vel ipsum vitae magna dictum feugiat. Maecenas sodales aliquam felis, sed lobortis diam ullamcorper efficitur. Nam in sapien mauris. Cras nisl risus, finibus quis turpis in, suscipit blandit elit. Mauris rutrum porta bibendum.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: my name is Fischer with a c.

Comment: I'm sorry! fixed (shouldn't you be able to edit it too?)